# React - Can't set state using Axios with GitHub API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

trying to set up a simple AJAX call with Axios in React.

I make the Axios call in my 'FetchRepos' component then require it in my 'Homepage' component passing a language argument.

It loads fine because I console.logged the data in Homepage component but when I put the function in set state I check in React dev tools and the 'repos' state is null and when I do the onClick method for 'activeLanguage' it simply removes 'repos' from state.

Help would be appreciated.

Homepage Component

```
import React from "react";
import {fetchPopularRepos} from "./FetchRepos";

class Homepage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            activeLanguage: 'all',
            repos: null
        }

        this.activeLanguage = this.activeLanguage.bind(this);
    }
    activeLanguage(lang) {
        this.setState({
            activeLanguage: lang,
            repos: fetchPopularRepos(lang)
        })

    }
    render() {
        var languages = ['all', 'ruby', 'javascript', 'python'];
        return (
            <div>
                {languages.map((lang) => {
                    return (
                        <li key={lang} onClick={this.activeLanguage.bind(null, lang)} style={lang === this.state.activeLanguage ? {color: 'red'} : null}>{lang}</li>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

FetchRepos Component

```
var axios = require('axios');

export function fetchPopularRepos(language) {
    axios.get('https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:>1+language:'+ language + '&sort=stars&order=desc&type=Repositories')
    .then(function(res) {
        return res.data.items;
    })
}
```

Comment: Your function fetchPopularRepos returns nothing, so you're just setting the repos property of the state to undefined

Comment: You can fix this by returning the result of axios get and setting the state in another then statement in your React component

Comment: Fair point on consistency KonradD.

@PatrickHund Can you explain further please? I don't understand why fetchPopularRepos returns nothing as I already did a console.log instead of return and it fetched an array of objects?

Secondly I tried this:

    activeLanguage(lang) {
        fetchPopularRepos(lang)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
        })
        this.setState({
            activeLanguage: lang
        })
    }

but got this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

if you could help explain why I'd be really grateful!

Comment: Sorry I'm on my phone can't write proper answer. You almost got it right, simply add "return" before axios.get

Comment: @PatrickHund Haha no problem mate, that worked so thanks! If you get time after your call and can be bothered if you could explain why I needed to add return would be great :) If not thanks anyway!

Comment: Maybe add these comments as and answer? @PatrickHund

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems here:

1- The axios function return a promise, so even with the promise your state won't be set up correctly. You must use asyn/await or handle the respond as a promise and set up the state inside a then function.

```
async activeLanguage(lang) {
      this.setState({
          activeLanguage: lang,
          repos: await fetchPopularRepos(lang)
      })

}
```

2- You must return something from the fetchPopularRepos function because your function is not returning anything. See my code below

BAD (Does not return any value)

```
function some(){
   var a = 1;
   var b = 2;
   var result = a + b
}
```

GOOD (Return a value)

```
function some(){
   var a = 1;
   var b = 2;
   return a + b
}
```

So, you return something because you want to catch whatever is the result in other piece of your code. Like this:

```
ver result = some()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I'm confused when you say I wasn't returning anything thought as I had 
.then(function(res) {
        return res.data.items;
    }) in my code. Is this not returning the results of the ajax request?

Comment: Yeah, but that is going to be the return of the get function of axios, see.. when you make axios.get() ... that is a function call .. so if you don't return that result.. not matter if you return something inside the then.. you are not returning anything.